# Conjectures prove or disprove

Tags: functions

Prove this conjecture by giving 3 examples or disprove it using 1 counterexample.

Prove the function $f(x) = \sqrt{x-2}$, over the domain $1 \leq x \leq 6$ will give a real solution.

Please help me with full explanation. Thank you! :)

Comment: $x-2\ge 0$ so $D_f=[2,\infty)$

Comment: Since you're new here, I'd like mention that it would help if you show what you have already tried. This lets us know where you got stuck, and allows us to better answer your question.  Also, showing your work demonstrates that you have invested some time in the problem, which increases the likelihood of getting a helpful answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Compute $f(1){}{}{}{}{}$.

**Edit 1:** *It was estabilished that the OP realises that only non-negative real numbers can be square-rooted*.

Having this in my mind, when you replace $x$ with $1$ in the expression that defines $f$, what  number will you be trying to find the square root of?

**Edit 2:** You get $f(1)=\sqrt{1-2}=\cdots$

Comment: @jycmndrn A full explanation might follow if you show you tried to understand my hint.

Comment: I don't know how to compute that either. Sorry. This is from our investigation assessment, and we're supposed to know this from our teachers last year. But, they didn't explain anything about this..

Comment: Are you the asker on a different computer?

Comment: Yes?? I'm new to this website. Sorry.

Comment: If you can't be in the same computer to follow your question, you should register so we can interact with you properly.

Comment: What do you know about square-rooting a number? What can you put substitute $x$ with in $\sqrt x$?

Comment: Try using [this page](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge). Fill out the form hidden under "click here" after point 3. Your old account is `http://math.stackexchange.com/users/70021/jycmdrn`

Comment: I can't see the 'add comment' hyperlinked button. So, I'm just going to use this. It's not possible to square-root a negative number. So, I can only substitute x with positive integers.

Comment: I believe this one is now registered. The first one I used was not.

Comment: You should now be able to comment, then. I added some stuff to my answer.

Comment: Is it 0? (the answer to your question, from your answer)

Comment: The 'add comment' button is not showing in your answer though.

Comment: It's working now. The answer would be square root of -1, which is impossible. We need to provide three examples to prove the conjecture. So, I tried substituting x with the numbers from the domain given. Is that right?

Comment: It's 50 points, to comment on others answers. http://math.stackexchange.com/privileges

Comment: @jycmdrn Exactly. So you can conclude that that function won't always give a real solution, because you've found a number to which it won't give a real solution. You should look at Adri's comment on your question and try to figure out what other values for $x$ won't work.

Comment: Okay. Thank you very much!

Comment: @jycmdrn You're welcome.